# Использование связей Active Record в Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Имеются два класса: Article (has_many comments) и Comment(belongs_to article).

Каким образом можно реализовать следующее: страница отображает все созданные статьи(article) и комментарии(comments), добавленные к статьям. В конец страницы прикрутить возможность добавления комментариев(comments) с выбором, к какой именно статье они будут принадлежать. Т.е. после списка всех статей и их комметарии прикручено окошко, в которое вводится текст комментария, под ним выпадающее меню с названиями статей -> выбираем статью, жмем "ОК" и комментарий к статье добавляется.

Проблема заключается именно в комментариях. Так как экшн new автоматически привязывает комментарий к конкретной статье.

Для понимания, это то, что уже имеется во вьюхе:

```html
<h1>Список всех задач</h1>

  <% @articles.each do |p| %>
    <h2><%= p.title %></h2>
      <% p.comments.each do |todo| %>
        <ul>
          <li><%= comment.text %></li>
        </ul>
  <% end %>

  <h2>Новая задача</h2>
    <%= form_for ([p, p.comments.build]) do |f| %>
      <p>
        <%= f.label :"Comment:" %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :text %><br>
      </p>

      <p>
        <%= f.submit 'OK'%>
      </p>
    <% end %>

<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Выберите статью</a>
      <ul>
        <li><???>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Контроллер статьи:

```html
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
@articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
  end
  
  def edit
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
@article = Article.create(article_params)
@article.save
redirect_to @article
  end

  def update
@article = Article.find(params[:id])

if @article.update(article_params)
  redirect_to @article
else
  render 'edit'
end
  end

  private
  def article_params
params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end
end
```

Контроллер комментарий:

```html
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
@article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
@comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

  private
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:goal, :isCompleted)
end
end
```

Comment: Для лучшего понимания ты бы еще выложил контролеры, а почему ты не хочешь использовать как в простом примере, зайти в статью и оставить комментарий там. Что тебе мешает сделать форму с селектом и текстовым полем и при комите сохранять в бд?
Вопрос отпадет после прочтения.http://rusrails.ru/getting-started-with-rails#dobavlyaem-vtoruyu-model

Comment: @an0mality, да, было бы проще. Возможно, статьи и комментарии не лучший к ним пример. Да, с сылкой знаком. 
Что если это список дел? Я сначала просто записываю дело, а потом уже решаю к какой именно категории относится оно.
И такого подхода требуют условия.

Comment: Определённо не лучший. А то вместо того, чтобы сделать как вы просите, очень хочется поставить ваше решение под сомнение. А что касается решения: [вы ищете `collection_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_select), скорее всего.

Comment: ну тогда как вариант сделайте отдельный роут, будет отдельный метод в контроллере, который будет создавать ваш комментарий к задаче, как ответил D-side, используйте новую форму где будет селект и текстовое поле для комментария и коммит. Я может и не так давно сам занимаюсь разработкой. но такой вариант как по мне лучше, ну и на мой взгляд, CRUD очень помогает при решении любого вопроса.

Comment: и возможно я не прав, но все же стоит придерживаться стандарта. сделайте страницу index со всеми задачами, и сделайте страничку show с 1 записью, где вы и сможете создать свой комментарий

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае я бы добавил в *routes.rb* строку

```
resources :comments, only: :create
```

Теперь на экшн CommentsController.create будет приводить 2 URL:

```
POST /articles/:article_id/comments
POST /comments
```

И в соответствующем экшене CommentsController.create можно добавить проверку

```
if params[:artical_id]
   # берем *:article_id* из *params*
else
   # берем *:article_id* из *comment_params*
end
```

Далее добавляем *:article_id* в метод *permit*

```
params.require(:comment).permit(:goal, :isCompleted, :article_id)
```

А во вьюхе описываем форму:

```
<%= form_for @comment do %>
  <%= f.collection_select :article_id, Article.all, :id, :ttitle %>
  <%= f.text_field :goal %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<%= end %>
```

где-то в индексе надо еще написать

```
@comment = Comment.new
```

Не уверен, что синтаксически написал всё верно, но надеюсь идея прозрачна.